# WSO2AM Pattern 2 deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am working on WSO2-3.0.0 version deployment patterns. Can anybody provide me details on how to configure **wso2am-3.0.0 pattern 2** deployment?

I found this page https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/deploying-wso2-api-manager/deployment-patterns/#wso2-api-manager-deployment-patterns. But doesn't contain sufficient details on how to deploy the setup

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the distributed deployment details[1]. So in pattern-2, you have a single server which runs as publisher, devportal and traffic manager. So you can refer to [1] and do all the required changes that single server that is mentioned in publisher, devportal and traffic manager.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/deploying-wso2-api-manager/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup/